# How to edit the CSS of a <content> selector in Polymer 1.0

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom

I am trying to use `<content>` to pull an element with the attribute 'header' but I am having trouble applying CSS to that pulled content.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <content id="headerText" select="[header]"></content>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#header ::content > #headerText {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Unless the colon doesn't belong to something in polymer, they cause an issue, so delete them and do this: `#header content#headerText`

Comment: The colons are part of the Polymer syntax, it does not work without them.

Comment: I think you fundamentally misunderstand how to use the content tags, maybe if you make a mock up of what you're trying to achieve we'll be able to help you more

Comment: I think your just mad. The issue was solved, just because it wasn't your answer please don't down vote the question.

Comment: @Ulsting I'm not mad sorry if I came across that way, generally using the content tags is a last resort. I'd advise you to use properties instead where you can.

Comment: @AndrewBone I think you don't know what Polymer is all about...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't know what will be replaced by the content just do this:

```
#header ::content * {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

it makes no sense to give an `id` to the content, since it will be replaced...
See the [Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#styling-distributed-children-content) on that point.

If you need other sibling of content, just add a wrapper like this:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <content id="headerText" select="[header]"></content>
  </div>
  <span>other stuff here</span>
</div>
```

and then

```
#wrapper ::content * {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That will only work if the content is in tags I think, #header > ::content will do all the content (it really depends what the op is going for)

Comment: While this works it does not allow to put anything else inside of the same div as the content.

Comment: that's why you need a wrapper to the content, see the documentation

Comment: depending on what you're trying to do properties might be a better solution anyway http://plnkr.co/edit/Go1hngYXTzCCUDRkHsHU?p=preview

Comment: @Ulsting I added a use-case with a sibling, does it work for you?

Answer (score -2):

You were close

```
<div id="header">
  <content id="headerText" select="[header]"></content>
</div>

#header > ::content #headerText {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I know that is what [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) says in its example, but just below that it has the > where I have it, neither way works for me.

Comment: OK the id of the content tag is not passed along to the dom

Comment: Yes, but I think you are missing the point of the content tag.  It is not supposed to contain anything natively, it is supposed to "pull" the element it is selecting, and "add" it to the current view. Putting text in the content element defeats the purpose of it.

Comment: then you put it out side <span id="headerText"><content></content></span> you call that with #header #headerText > ::content

Answer (score -3):

See example maybe used for you: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpmLvmL3/)

CSS:

```
#header content#headerText {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
 <content id="headerText" select="[header]">111</content>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what the <content> tag is supposed to do. It grabs the html element from the parent directory, adding content to it defeats this purpose.